# LED bulbs or dimmer switch causing buzzing?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, led, dimmer-switch, noise

I installed a light fixture that contains 4 **dimmable** GU10 LED lightbulbs.  I also installed a dimmer switch (Feit Electric Model 72200) for the fixture.

When I dim the bulbs to 50-85% on, I hear a distinct buzzing sound coming from the bulbs.

Can the buzzing be caused by a defective dimmer switch, or is it simply a case of poor quality LED bulbs?

Will buying different bulbs likely fix the issue?

Comment: What model dimmer?

Comment: What model LED?  Does the dimmer documentation list the LEDs as supported?  Does the LED documentation list the dimmer as supported?   These things can get a bit complicated...

Comment: @Tyson Good question.  Answer: Feit Electric Model 72200.

Comment: @Harper The bulbs came with the light fixture.  They are Great Value brand (Walmart).  There is no documentation with the bulbs except that that they are dimmable.  The dimmer documentation does state that LED bulbs are supported.

Comment: I think your hunch is correct. The storebrand bulbs of course "fell off a truck in Shenzhen".  Feit Electric, Utilitech and Lights of America are not great brands either. Annoyances like buzzy bulbs are just the price of buying cheap.  Evading having to design for and support this kind of problem is the point of cheap brands.

Comment: an LED comnpatible dimmer can drive cheap LEDs w/o hum. good bulbs can work with older dimmers without hum.